# glewInit() returns with Error: '1.5.2'

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am running some OpenGL programs on Linux. Can't understand why I receive error when initializing glew. (Error 1.5.2)

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
 GLenum res = glewInit();

 if(res != GLEW_OK)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetString(res));
    return 1;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

which is run by:

```
g++ 1.cpp -lGLEW
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the wrong function. What you want is

```
glewGetErrorString(res);
```

It looks like you're getting the version number right now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GLEW Usage](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) page:

> First you need to create a valid OpenGL rendering context and call glewInit() to initialize the extension entry points.

Almost anything related to OpenGL requires you to begin with a context. The examples on the aforementioned page use [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php) to get the context, but there are other ways to do it.

Regarding your error code, @mwerschy is correct that you should be using `glewGetErrorString(res);` rather than `glewGetString(res)`, which returns the version of GLEW.